# sql unmatched keys with criteria

Tags: sql, select, join, ms-access-2013

This is almost a left-join situation, but I don't see how to express it in sql. 
Consider a table `Orders` with fields `User, Item, Flag`. We need a list of Users who appear in the table, but who have no rows where Flag=True. (None of these fields have nulls.) Equivalently, Flag=False in all rows for the User, and there are such rows.

I would naively write:
`SELECT T1.User FROM Orders AS T1 LEFT JOIN Orders AS T2 ON T1.User=T2.User WHERE T2.Flag=TRUE AND T2.User IS NULL`
to select rows on the right and then check for the join getting no matches, but of course that doesn't work, as it applies both criteria to rows on the right

I tried:
`SELECT T1.User FROM Orders AS T1 WHERE T1.User NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT User FROM Orders WHERE Flag=TRUE)`
but on Microsoft Access, this is *extremely* slow, as if the second select is being run for each row of the first.

Thus far, the only solution has been to create a temporary table from the second select. But it's such a simple problem, there must be a good way to express it in sql. (Apologies if this is obvious; I'm still feeling my way through the complicated semantics of sql.)

Comment: Try `T1.User=NULL` in first query. And why use distinct in second query? Frequently discussed in the SQL world, the [LEFT JOIN NULL, NOT IN, NOT EXISTS](http://www.google.com/search?q=left+join+vs+not+in) are interchangeable for non-match record queries.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery solution is sound and I can't imagine why it's slow unless you have indexing issues. As for your question, I'm not sure I entirely understand, but if you have issues in which your filter conditions are being applied to both tables, then try adding the condition to the join condition instead of the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT T1.User 
FROM Orders AS T1 

LEFT JOIN Orders AS T2 
ON T1.User=T2.User 
AND T2.Flag = 'TRUE'

WHERE T2.Flag=TRUE 
AND T2.User IS NULL
```